# Yii2 AccessControl giving Forbidden 403 when using HTTPBearerAuth in Rest API

Tags: php, rest, yii2, yii2-validation

I am authenticating on my base controller using HTTPBearerAuth

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

On my UserController extending base controller and using `AccessControl` to allow guest users to access login.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
            [
                'actions' => ['logout'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $behaviors['verbs'] = [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'logout' => ['post'],
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

When I try to access login without authentication details, I get

```
{
  "name": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "You are requesting with an invalid credential.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 401,
  "type": "yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

Unauthorized 401. With authentication details, I get

```
{
  "name": "Forbidden",
  "message": "You are not allowed to perform this action.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 403,
  "type": "yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException"
}
```

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take out AccessControl and use HTTPBearerAuth in child behaviors using `only` or `except`.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    //authentication only applies to actionIndex in child controller
    $behaviors['authenticator']['only'][] = 'index';

    return $behaviors;
}
```